# Why doesn't $ in .NET multiline regular expressions match CRLF?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, line-breaks

I have noticed the following:

```
var b1 = Regex.IsMatch("Line1\nLine2", "Line1$", RegexOptions.Multiline);   // true
var b2 = Regex.IsMatch("Line1\r\nLine2", "Line1$", RegexOptions.Multiline); // false
```

I'm confused. The documentation of [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) says:

> **Multiline**: 
>   Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so they match at the beginning and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the beginning and end of the entire string.

Since C# and VB.NET are mainly used in the Windows world, I would guess that most files processed by .NET applications use CRLF linebreaks (`\r\n`) rather than LF linebreaks (`\n`). Still, it seems that the .NET regular expression parser does not recognize a CRLF linebreak as an *end of line*.

I know that I could workaround this, for example, by matching `Line1\r?$`, but it still strikes me as strange. Is this really the intended behaviour of the .NET regexp parser or did I miss some hidden `UseWindowsLinebreaks` option?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From MSDN:

> By default, $ matches only the end of the input string. If you specify the RegexOptions.Multiline option, it matches either the newline character (\n) or the end of the input string. It does not, however, match the carriage return/line feed character combination. To successfully match them, use the subexpression \r?$ instead of just $.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Multiline

So I can't say why (compatibility with regular expressions from other languages?), but at the very least it's intended.

Comment: Surprising, but at least well-defined. Thanks for digging that up!

Comment: Interestingly, it is widely accepted (and defined) across regular expression implementations that $ matches a _position_, **not** a _literal_. So for MSDN to say it matches a newline character isn't entirely correct either.

Comment: +1 There is a _long_ history (and thus a stromg precedent) of `$` matching before a linefeed in multi-line mode. Making it behave differently by default would have been a bad move by MS. However, they could have added a .NET specific modifier to make `$` match: `(?=[\r\n]|\z)` (which is probably the expression you are looking for here).

Comment: The other puzzling thing (consistent with this) is that .NET allows the dot to match `\r`, even it is set to not match newline characters.

Comment: This is rather annoying behaviour, especially as Microsoft still (in this day and age) continue to use a pointless extra byte for their newline marker.

Comment: I created a ticket on GitHub so we can voice our displeasure on this behavior https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28410

Comment: @JohnZabroski Don't get your hopes too high, that's a huge breaking change

Comment: Why would it be a breaking change?

Comment: @JohnZabroski Ooooh my bad, I read the description too quickly, I thought you wanted to change the default behavior

Comment: The accepted answer explains why $ does not work in .Net, but the replacement \r?$ is very wrong, please use as suggested by ridgerunner (?=[\r\n]|\z).