# different output with same regex...why

Tags: regex, string, powershell

i have a file ids.txt

```
646646646
995775665
564548984
566466464
553553663
144235535
```

why the output between this two code is different:

```
PS > [regex]::Replace($file,'^([0-9])([0-9]+)([0-9])$','$3$2$1')

646646646 595775669 464548985 466466465 353553665 544235531

PS> $file -replace '^([0-9])([0-9]+)([0-9])$','$3$2$1'

646646646
595775669
464548985
466466465
353553665
544235531
```

THANK and sorry for my bad english

### update:

```
$_ofs = $Ofs
$ofs = "`r`n"
[regex]::Replace($file,'^([0-9])([0-9]+)([0-9])$','$3$2$1','multiline')
$ofs = $_ofs


646646646
995775665
564548984
566466464
553553663
544235531
```

why the result is not correct ?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell converts $file to a string in order to assign it to the [string] parameter of the [regex]::Replace() method. The resulting value of this string is dependent upon the value of your $OFS global variable which currently appears to be a space ' '.

This should give you the same result as -replace:

```
$file | foreach { [regex]::Replace($_,'^([0-9])([0-9]+)([0-9])$','$3$2$1') }
```

Updated answer:

The CLR [regex]::Replace() method does not match on `r (carriage return). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8618642/873131).

You *could* set $OFS = "`n", but it is rarely a good idea to set global vars in your scripts.

If you do indeed need to perform the replace on a multiline string (instead of per line as in my previous answer), then you have a few other options:

1: Read the file in as a single string and remove the CRs:
    $file = (Get-Content '.\file.txt' -Raw) -replace "`r"

2: Read the file in per line and join on LF:
    $file = (Get-Content '.\file.txt') -join "`n"

It is generally considered a best practice to "stream" your data, however. This way the user can get feedback *during* the operation. Too often, you see poorly written applications that appear to hang when performing large disk operations, leaving the user not knowing if there is a problem or not. For small files it really makes no difference though, although I would still recommend using the -replace operator where you can.

Another thing to note here, [regex]::Replace() is always going to return a single string, whether it be singleline or multiline, e.g. if you pass it an array of 10 strings, the strings are joined, passed to the method as a single string, and a single string is returned.

However, the -replace operator returns what it is given. If you pass it a string it returns a string; if you pass it an array (as in your case, presumably), it returns an array.