# What is any character (including new line) pattern in regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Does regex have a pattern that match any characters including new line in regex? The `dot` pattern match any characters but isn't including new line, (currently, I'm using `[^~]` because the `~` character is rarely use).

**Edit:** I'm using `regex` with `C#` language.

Comment: Which dialect of regex — or which host language?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm using `regex` with `C#`, I don't know if C# implementation of `regex` have any differents from original regex

Comment: Yes; there are lots of differences between the regexes in C# and 'the original regex' — but almost nothing except the `ed` editor uses the original regex. Oh, and plain vanilla `grep`.  When asking about regexes, it is important to specify the host language, because what works in C# may not work in PHP, Perl, Tcl/Tk, Python, Ruby, C, C++, `grep`, `grep -E`, `sed`, `ed`, Java, etc., and vice versa.

Comment: Haha , i though was perl ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks you for the interesting informations. So is there a pattern to match any characters including new line that works with C# implementation of regex?

Comment: You'll need to get an answer from someone who knows C#; said person is not me.  My C is blunt, or flat, or natural; anything but sharp.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618557/why-doesnt-in-net-multiline-regular-expressions-match-crlf

Comment: isn't matching all chars including newline is simply the string itself? the pattern match **all** characters...

Comment: @NirMH: in most dialects of regex, `.*` matches any sequence of characters except newline and NUL `'\0'`.  Hence the use of a negated character class in the question.  Personally, I'd probably use `[^^A]` (not control-A) or something similar; that's even less likely to be a character that's used very often.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using <kbd>#C</kbd>, you can use the [RegexOptions.Singleline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Singleline) compiler flag.

> Use single-line mode, where (`.`) matches every character (instead of every character except `\n`)

And instead of the RegexOptions.Singleline compiler flag, you can get the same effect by placing an inline modifier at the very beginning of your regular expression.

```
Regex.Match(input, @"(?s)foo.*bar");
```

Answer (score 7):

I am not familiar with C#, but I am sure regex works the identically everywhere.

`.*` Matches any character, right, excepts for `\n`. A simple way to surpass this is eighter by using capture groups: `(.|\n)*`; `(.|\n|\r)*`, or you can surpass this limitation by using `[\s\S]`, where `\s` is any whitespace, and `\S` is any non white space. I believe in some languages `[^]` will work as well, but don't know about C#. Basically it says do not match nothing, so it will match anything.

Answer (score 0):

[\s\S] matches any char in a c# Program.

It does not however match in the Visual Studio editor (tested with VS2022), even when specifying the Singleline flag : (?s).

In the Visual Studio editor regex search, you need to use [\n\s\S] to match any char.