# Matching regex across newlines

Tags: c#

Building this regex

```
string regExStr1 = @"^(?<year>([1-2]\d{3}|\d{2}))-(?<month>(1[0-2]|0\d|\d))-(?<day>(3[0-1]|[0-2]\d|\d)),(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),(?<close>\d+(\.\d+)),(?<high>\d+(\.\d+)),(?<low>\d+(\.\d+)),(?<open>\d+(\.\d+)),(?<volume>\d+),(?<ignored>\d+)$";
```

I can match

```
var csvContent = "2017-09-07,15:35:00,64.85,64.98,64.85,64.85,16204,0";
```

but if I add a new line of values, it doesn't match anything.

```
var csvContent = "2017-09-07,15:35:00,64.85,64.98,64.85,64.85,16204,0\r\n2017-09-07,15:35:00,64.85,64.98,64.85,64.85,16204,0";
```

I have played around with `Singleline, Multiline`

```
  var regex = new Regex(regExStr1, RegexOptions.Multiline);
  var matches = regex.Matches(csvContent );
```

Not sure how to match on strings across newlines?

Comment: You must add `\r?` before `$`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618557/why-doesnt-in-net-multiline-regular-expressions-match-crlf

Comment: This is really tricky. Using Multiline, If I have just \r, it doesn't match it. If I have \r\n, it does. Thanks,