# Why doesn't C# RegEx class respect Environment.NewLine?

Tags: c#, regex, newline

I'm using C# interactive, and here is the setup:

```cs
#r "System.Text.RegularExpressions"
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string s = "Number 42" + Environment.NewLine + "and 1 number 3";
```

I'm looking to add brackets around all numbers at the end of a line, or at end of string (42 and 3 should both get brackets).

> Note: on my system `Environment.NewLine` is **`\r\n`**

So I try `Regex.Replace(s, "(\\d+)$", "[$0]", RegexOptions.Multiline)` and only the 3 gets wrapped.

If I do `Regex.Replace(s, "(\\d+)\r?$", "[$0]", RegexOptions.Multiline)` both get wrapped but one has an extra \r inside the brackets. So the regex engine is believing the lie that `Environment.NewLine` is **`\n`**.

Is there a separate `Environment.NewLine` setting just for regexes? If so, how do I set it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but shouldn't it be unnecessary?

Comment: `$` is only looking for `\n` but `Environment.NewLine` is `\r\n` so `(\\d+)$` is insufficient because a `\r` is messing you up.

Comment: Here is similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8618557/5311735. In short, it just works like this, probably because regexes has long history before .NET, so to be consistent with all other implementations.

Comment: @Evk That's a worthy dupe target.

Comment: Actually, it is only partly a dupe of that thread because here, the numbers must be wrapped with brackets without the CR symbol (the current OP regex is not actually doing what OP needs).

Answer (score 3):

The `$` anchor is a regex construct. The [`Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netcore-3.1) ("*`\r\n` for non-Unix platforms, or `\n` for Unix platforms*") is not referred to from within the regex library and is a separate property.

You can use

```cs
Regex.Replace(s, @"\d+(?=\r?$)", "[$&]", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%5Cr%3F%24%29&i=Number%2042%0D%0Aand%201%20number%203&r=%5B%24%26%5D&o=m):

[image]

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?=\r?$)` - followed with an optional CR then followed with the end of the line.

The point is that when you use `RegexOptions.Multiline` the `$` anchor matches a location right before the LF (`\n`) symbol. There is no way to redefine this behavior. The `Environment.NewLine` in Windows inserts `CRLF` line ending sequence, so you get `\r\n` as line endings. So, adding `\r?` before `$` is a valid way to match end of line positions.

Comment: So what's the relation between $ and Environment.NewLine? None?

Comment: @NH. `$` is a regex construct. [`Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netcore-3.1) ("*`\r\n` for non-Unix platforms, or `\n` for Unix platforms.*") is a .NET property, it is not part and not referred to from within the regex library.